# Setting Environment variable in LINUX using python in threads

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables

i have five threads in my code...

five threads are initiated by the main.py

so for each running thread i need to set diff IP as environment value

```
thread-1: has to set 192.168.10.2
thread-2: has to set 192.168.10.3
thread-3: has to set 192.168.10.4
thread-4: has to set 192.168.10.5
thread-5: has to set 192.168.10.6
```

please guide me in solving this

Comment: You can't have separate environment variables for each thread.

Comment: `os.environ['SOME_VAR'] = 25`  or maybe `os.putenv('somevar','someval')` , or even `os.system("set x=y")` ... but as others have said it will not work very well if many threads are setting the same var

Answer (score 8):

Environment variables are set on a per-process basis, not a per-thread one.